# Bash script find behaviour

Tags: bash, find

```
     for subj in `cat dti_list.txt`; do
     echo $subj
     find . -type f -iname '*306.nii' -execdir bash -c 'rename.ul "$subj" DTI_MAIN_AP.nii *.nii' \+
```

done

I have some trouble with a small bash script, which adds the name instead of replacing when I use the rename.ul function. 
Currently, the code adds DTI_MAIN_AP.nii in front of the old name.

My goal is to replace the name from the subj list and using the find to search up any directory with a *306.nii file, and then using execdir to execute the rename.ul function to rename the file from the dti_list.txt.

Any solution, or correction to get the code working, will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that Bash notation?  `foreach` isn't a Bash command according to the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).  Is that some sort of extension you're using?

Comment: Ignoring that this isn't anything close to valid bash syntax -- substituting strings into code is extremely dangerous -- a maliciously-named file could run arbitrary code.

Comment: Also, we really need to know more about how this `rename.ul` "function" is defined. If it's really a function, it'll only be accessible to a child-process subshell if exported or redefined therein.

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Do you suggest using the mv command instead?  And do pardon the foreach line, I wasn't thinking, just a relapse from tcsh, it's corrected now with proper bash. The rename.ul, is the regular rename.ul comand from linux. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rename.ul.1.html

Comment: I don't know what `rename.ul` does or is expected to do, so I can't say whether `mv` should be used instead.

Comment: So you want to find all files matching `*306.nii`, and rename them to `DTI_MAIN_AP.nii` (with the assumption that only one such file will exist in a given directory)?

Comment: And btw, `rename.ul` is not particularly standard; it's the way Debian and Ubuntu distinguish the util-linux `rename` command from a more widespread Perl utility under the same name. If you *can* use `mv` (which is POSIX-standardized, and thus guaranteed to behave the same way everywhere), you certainly should.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the essences of it.

Comment: Where does `dti_list.txt` come into that?

Comment: I was using it to limit which directories to change, but with your help I got it to rename and not add. So thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to rename the first file matching `*306.nii` in each directory to `DTI_MAIN_AP.nii`, that might look like:

```
find . -type f -iname '*306.nii' \
  -execdir sh -c '[[ -e DTI_MAIN_AP.nii ]] || mv "$1" DTI_MAIN_AP.nii' _ {} +
```

---

If instead of matching on `*306.nii` you want to iterate over names from `dti_list.txt`, that might instead look like:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename <&3; do
  find . -type f -name "$filename" \
    -execdir sh -c '[[ -e DTI_MAIN_AP.nii ]] || mv "$1" DTI_MAIN_AP.nii' _ {} +
done <dti_list.txt
```

References of note:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) (on reading files line-by-line)
- [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious, then, as to whether my edits since first posted make this better or worse in your view; I'm still not certain I understand the question.

Comment: The second suggestion was the essens of it. But I was using it to limit which directories to change the files in. Some dirs have files from *305.nii to *308.nii and other have *306.nii to *309.nii and others have from *.307 to 3010.etc. so I used the DTI file to limit which files to change in order to rename the correct *30*.nii file to DTI_MAIN_AP.nii. Not an elegant solution but workable for me.